# How to make my bard not too obnoxious

Tags: character-creation, roleplaying, bard, background

I am kinda new to tabletop RPGs.  I am am playing with the idea of making a Bard who wanted to be some kind of hero and only became a Bard to be able to create his own tales about himself and become famous that way. I would like him to think of his art as some kind of tool and nothing else.

My problem is that I don't have any idea how not to make this character absolutely obnoxious and horrible to play with for the rest of the party.
Does anyone have an idea of why he would not be too obnoxious or should I rethink it entirely?

Comment: This site focuses on questions with specific answers. Your question is the kind that is looking for thoughts, ideas, and suggestions. That isn’t handled by this site, but we do have a [list of suggested RPG discussion sites](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/321) where questions like that can be asked and ideas given.